# How to retrieve a full URL from a short one? Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, url

I'm needing some help on how to retrieve the full URL from a short one.
For example: http://tinysong.com/HJ9h
If you click that link it will open a grooveshark url. How can i retrieve the original grooveshark url?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short URLs work by HTTP redirection.  You can set up an `NSURLConnection` with a request with the short URL and set a delegate.  In the delegate, implement the method:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
```

If `response` is non-`nil`, it's a redirect. You can examine the response. You can check if it's actually an instance of `NSHTTPURLResponse` using `-isKindOfClass:` and then get additional data from it.

Also, you can examine the new `request` that `NSURLConnection` proposes. Its `URL` property will be the new URL to which the server redirected your connection request.

If you were redirected and you have reason to believe that you won't be redirected further and that's all you were interested in, you can cancel the connection request by invoking `-cancel` on the connection object.

---

Update.  Here's some sample code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static BOOL stop;

@interface MyDelegate : NSObject
@end

@implementation MyDelegate

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"request %@", request);
    NSLog(@"response %@", response);
    return response ? nil : request;
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s: error %@", __func__, error);
    stop = TRUE;
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
    stop = TRUE;
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tinysong.com/HJ9h"]];
    MyDelegate* del = [[MyDelegate alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:del];
    while (!stop)
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
request <NSURLRequest http://tinysong.com/HJ9h>
response (null)
request <NSURLRequest http://grooveshark.com/#!/s/~/3Xl6OQ?src=11>
response <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x103500340>
-[MyDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:]
```

Comment: i've tried using that and that method is working perfectly. but i have a question. inside that method what's the command to retrieve the url? example code would be nice. thanks

Comment: This should provide the new URL: `[request URL]`.

Comment: Are you checking only when `response` is non-`nil`? `NSURLConnection` may call that delegate method even before it really initiates the connection attempt merely to inform the delegate that is has "canconicalized" the origin request. So, not every request of that delegate method is for a redirect.

Comment: i check if response is non-nil and i put an NSLog of the [request URL] inside the if (if reponse is non-nil). it doesnt do anything, doesnt NSLog, so it's nil.

Comment: Right, but you're probably canceling the connection. My point is that you need to let the connection continue in the case where `response` is `nil` because that was not a redirect. I have updated my answer with code which demonstrates what's going on. From the output you see one invocation of the `willSendRequest` method that's not a redirect and then another invocation with the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the API of e. g. [LongURL](http://longurl.org/api) or [Untiny](http://untiny.me/api/).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it from the Terminal

```
curl --head shorturl
```

This will display just the short header and you can see the url in there.

For example

```
$ curl --head http://tinysong.com/HJ9h
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanenty
Server: sharkattack!
Date: Sat, 05 May 2012 22:13:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: TinysongSessionID=4518ef13c93199344a23bb9fe9af3e98; expires=Sat, 02-May-2015 22:13:10 GMT; path=/
Location: http://grooveshark.com/#!/s/~/3Xl6OQ?src=11
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Expires: Sat, 05 May 2012 22:18:10 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Hostname: rhl082
X-N-Hostname: RHL082
```

And you can see the url that it points to is in the `Location` field.

So, using this with an NSTask will give you a result string that you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the service uses HTTP 301,302 one 303 redirects you could make a HTTP request to the initial URL...

If the response headers return 301,302 or 303 again then make another request to the new location specified in the header... You would then repeat this until the status code is something else, ie 200...

Then you can read the host and path from the response header and vola, you have your long URL..

Now in terms of getting the headers...  I use ASIHTTPRequest for all my networking needs... http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use it has an option to follow redirects so I presume if you make the request you will then be able to read the ResponseHeaders and get the long URL.

Hope that makes some sense